# Why are the attributes of Plot changing?

Tags: plotting, attributes, hold

In version 9, with a newly started *Mathematica* session, try the following code:

```
plotAttributes = Attributes[Plot]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];

Attributes[Plot]

% == plotAttributes
```

> `{Protected, ReadProtected}`
>
> `{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}`
>
> `False`

Is there any explanation why `Plot` doesn't have `HoldAll` as one of its attributes when a fresh *Mathematica* session is started, and acquires this attribute only after I call `Plot` once?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because, in version 9, the implementation of `Plot` is loaded from a dump file on its first usage, rather than loading when the kernel starts. One can see this by clearing the `ReadProtected` attribute:

```
ClearAttributes[Plot, ReadProtected]
Information[Plot]

(* -> Plot := System`Dump`AutoLoad[
        Hold[Plot], Hold[syms], Visualization`Proto`
       ] /; System`Dump`TestLoad *)
```

where `syms` is a large sequence of symbols (including `Plot` itself) whose usage will cause the dump file containing the `Plot` implementation to be loaded, if it has not been already. The file in question is (as `` Visualization`Proto` `` suggests):

```
FileNameJoin[{
 $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", "SystemResources", $SystemID,
 "Visualization", "Proto.mx"
}]
```

Since the definition of `Plot` needed for the autoloading functionality constitutes a single ownvalue, it does not matter whether `Attributes[Plot]` contains `HoldAll` or not, because there are no downvalues defined at this stage. After the full implementation is loaded, the attribute becomes necessary and therefore is set, but because heads are always evaluated before bodies, `HoldAll` is effectively present from the start. We can observe the same behavior in this example:

```
f := Function[Null, Null, HoldAll];
f@Print["evaluation leak!"] (* does not print anything *)
```

Comment: @Brett if not to make the kernel start up more quickly, could you perhaps add an answer outlining the reason for this change, assuming it's not too complicated to admit a brief explanation?

Comment: @Brett and Oleksandr thanks for the explanation. This comes up whenever we try to explain why tables of functions have to be plotted with `Plot[Evaluate[...]...]`, and now the explanation has just become a little more complicated. At least there is one.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @BrettChampion Except that I can't tell people: "look at the attributes of `Plot` before using it, to understand that it will hold its arguments and therefore won't recognize a `Table` of functions as separate functions". I now have to say: "Use `Evaluate`, trust me. You can find the explanation after you make the plot."

Comment: @BrettChampion - Then, shouln't the documentation for Plot include a "Possible Issues" section that points this out?