# Why can I define N[MySymbol] := ...?

Tags: core-language, language-design, attributes, downvalues

As far as I understand, I cannot define the values of built-in functions: `Sin[Cat] := Dog` will result in error.
This is because all built-in symbols have attribute `Protected`.

However for the function `N[]`, which is also protected, I can define a custom value:

`N[Cat] := Dog`

By the way, doing so will not change `DownValues[N]`.

So the question is: why function `N[]` behaves like that? Is it just some hard-coded rule, which is not described in terms of attributes, downvalues etc.?

Comment: It's actually in the `NValues`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128444/1871

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89607/12

Comment: Read the [Defining Numerical Values](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningNumericalValues.html) tutorial in the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Values of this type are actually stored in an analog to `DownValues` called `NValues`. Here's an example:

```
In[13]:= N[IndianaPi] = 4;
IndianaPi // NValues

Out[14]= {HoldPattern[
   N[IndianaPi, {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}]] :> 4}
```

As xzczd points out this is mostly a subset of what's mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128444/how-can-i-define-a-new-symbolic-constant-like-pi)

Note that a similar mechanism is used for `Format`:

```
In[43]:= Format[IndianaPi] =
  Interpretation[I\[Pi], IndianaPi];
IndianaPi // FormatValues
```

Per bcp's comment, the `Protected` attribute need not be a problem because no assignment to `N` is actually ever done. For instance:

```
In[118]:= A /: HoldPattern@Set[A[q_], v_] := (q -> v);

In[119]:= Protect@A

Out[119]= {"A"}

In[120]:= A[1] = 2

Out[120]= 1 -> 2
```

That gives us no error. And yet:

```
In[121]:= Attributes@A

Out[121]= {Protected}
```

Comment: But the question was why `N`'s `Protected` attribute does not forbid me to write `N[***] = ***`?

Comment: I'll address that. We can do the same thing with `UpValues`. I don't know how it's implemented internally.

Comment: @bcp realized I didn't tag you so you probably didn't see that.